# Can we use CA signed certificate like let's encrypt in softether vpn server?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, certificate-authority, lets-encrypt, softether

I am trying to attach let's encrypt certificate to my softether vpn server, But didn't found a way for it. Can we use CA signed certificate like let's encrypt in vpn server ? If yes, then please provide the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main challenge in using Let's Encrypt certificates with a VPN server is that their validity period is really short, only 3 months. This means there are some prerequisites:

- You must be able to automate loading of the certificate and the private key once the Certbot has renewed them. Luckily, Softether has a [Command Line Management Utility](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual). You should be familiar at least with [6.2 General Usage of `vpncmd`](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual/6.2_General_Usage_of_vpncmd) in order to understand the steps 1 and 3 in this answer.
- The VPN server needs to be publicly accessible on HTTP port 80 for the [HTTP-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge). Also, the Softether VPN server hasn't builtin HTTP-01 challenge, so it requires an external Certbot.

Steps:

1. You should add Let's Encrypt as trusted CA for the VPN clients.

   - You can find the currently active Intermediate Certificates from the [Chain of Trust](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) page.
   - The command is `CertAdd [path]`, from [6.5.6 "CertAdd": Add Trusted CA Certificate](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual/6.5_VPN_Client_Management_Command_Reference#6.5.6_.22CertAdd.22:_Add_Trusted_CA_Certificate).
   - *This step is probably possible with the GUI, too, but I'm not a GUI guy. :)*
2. Install and configure Certbot: [instructions based on your web server and system](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions).
3. Create a script / task / cronjob that periodically updates the certificate and the key.

   - Certbot renews all certificates that will expire in a month. Therefore, there's up to month before a the old certificate expires, but you in order to minimize the chances for this to fail, I'd recommend running this script at least once a week.
   - The command, from [6.3.20 "ServerCertSet": Set SSL Certificate and Private Key of VPN Server](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual/6.3_VPN_Server_%2F%2F_VPN_Bridge_Management_Command_Reference_(For_Entire_Server)#6.3.20_.22ServerCertSet.22:_Set_SSL_Certificate_and_Private_Key_of_VPN_Server), is:

     ```
     ServerCertSet [/LOADCERT:cert] [/LOADKEY:key]
     ```

     > `/LOADCERT` Specify the X.509 format certificate file to use.
     >
     > `/LOADKEY` Specify the Base 64 encoded private key file for the certificate to use.

     For example with Debian Linux, the command might be:

     ```
     vpncmd /server localhost /password:password /adminhub:DEFAULT
         /cmd ServerCertSet \
         /LOADCERT:/etc/letsencrypt/live/vpn.example.com/cert.pem \
         /LOADKEY:/etc/letsencrypt/live/vpn.example.com/privkey.pem
     ```

Comment: it is about one week I was looking for the solution. I could finally install LetEncrypt on the server and successfully connect to the server using SSTP client. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not required that the VPN server being publicly accessible on port 80 for the letsencrypt challenge. You can use the --preferred-challenges DNS option which and create a DNS txt record for your host.

For example:
certbot certonly -d yourhost.your.domain --manual --preferred-challenges dns

This will give you a prompt to create the new dns txt record

---

Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.yourhost.your.domain with the following value:

somerandomlygeneratedkey

Before continuing, verify the record is deployed.

---